# How do I use parameters to zoom in on a specific part of a path?

Tags: parameters, path, zooming, google-maps-static-api

I have created a static Google map with three markers and a path to show a train route with two legs (Stockholm-Gothenburg and Gothenburg-Halmstad).

How do I use parameters in the url to zoom in on the second leg (Gothenburg-Halmstad)?